# Element-wise derivative of the inverse of a matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, inverse

I would appreciate if you could help me to obtain the element-wise derivative of 
$Z = (-A-BX)^{(-1)}$ where all of elements of $A$, $B$ and $X$ are positive. I conjecture that if I increase any of $X$ elements, then the associated element of $Z$ will also increase.

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 1):

You need the thing  to be invertible; positivity  does not guarantee that. Assuming it is, use the formula
$$(M+\Delta M)^{-1} = M^{-1} - M^{-1}(\Delta M)M^{-1} + o(\|\Delta M\|) $$
which follows from the expansion of $(1-t)^{-1}$.

Changing $X$ to $X+\Delta X$ in your formula produces 
  $$(A+BX)^{-1} B(\Delta X) (A+BX)^{-1} \tag1$$
Your conjecture   amounts to saying that (1) has nonnegative entries whenever $\Delta X$ does. This appears to be false in general, since $(A+BX)^{-1}$ may have negative entries.